# Фейсбук - социальный плагин "Стена комментариев"

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

**Здравствуйте.** есть проблема. Поставил **соцстену** фейсбука. Она у меня под каждой новостью на разных страницах сайта. В настройках кода стены есть **URL**, но он идет только на главную страницу или такую на которою сам укажешь.

**Вопрос:** как сделать, чтобы **URL определялся автоматически** для кадой страницы, чтобы не писать его каждый раз вручную. Много чего пробовал не получается, так как во многих вещах не силен.

**Вот пример:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
 <script>(function(d){ 
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} 
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; 
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1 "; 
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js); 
 }(document));</script> 
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://copimytest.ucoz.ru" data-num-posts="2" data-width="680"></div>
```

Мне надо чтобы: **data-href="http://copimytest.ucoz.ru"** автоматом определялся для каждой страницы.

Кто знает, прошу помогите. Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ну как вариант можно использовать javascript или jquery.

```
<head>
...
function onload() {
document.getElementsByClassName[0].setAttribute("data-href", location.href)
// $(".fb-comments").attr("data-href", location.href);
}
</head>
<body onLoad="onload();">
...
```

Comment: А куда это и как вставлять, можно немного поподробее, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<script>document.write(location.href);</script>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="680"></div>`
По идее, должен быть еще юкозовский тег, но я не силен в Юкозе.

Comment: не не без юкоза, это просто у меня там тест-сайт). Но к сожелению не выходит, пишет внизу под стенкой: Warning: http://<script>document.write(location.href);</script> is unreachable.